# Coefficients of a series expansion under modular arithmetic

Tags: modular-arithmetic, integer-partitions

I am reading a paper by Ramanujan on partitions and need help understanding an intermediate step he uses in a proof. He writes:

> ... all the coefficients in $(1-x)^{-5}$ are multiples of 5, except those of $1$,  $x^5$, $x^{10}$, $...$, which are congruent to 1: that is to say
>   $$
> \dfrac{1}{(1-x)^5} \equiv \dfrac{1}{1-x^5} \pmod 5
> $$
>   or$$
> \dfrac{1-x^5}{(1-x)^5} \equiv 1 \pmod 5
> $$

The coefficients can easily be verified to have this property, we have the series expansion:

$$
(1-x)^{-5} = 1 + 5x + 15x^2 + 35x^3 +70x^4 + 126x^5 + \dots
$$

Here's how I would approach it. For the series expansion I can write:

$$
\begin{align}
(1-x)^{-5} &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{k+4}{4}x^k\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac{(k+4)!}{4!k!} x^k\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac{(k+4)(k+3)(k+2)(k+1)}{4!}x^k\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac{24 + 50 k + 35 k^2 + 10 k^3 + k^4}{24}x^k
\end{align}
$$

and looking at the coefficients modulo 5:

$$
\dfrac{24 + 50 k + 35 k^2 + 10 k^3 + k^4}{24} \equiv 1-k^4 \pmod 5
$$

and I can see that $k \equiv 0$ gives the coefficient congruent to 1 while any other value of k results in the coefficient being congruent to 0, the desired result. Still, I'm confused at the relevance/meaning of the congruences that Ramanujan wrote. Can someone help me understand what he meant? I feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: The congruences values happen to be the description of the coefficients of $\frac{1}{1-x^5}=1+x^5+x^{10}+...$. Namely, they are all zero except for exponents divisible by $5$, which are $1$. He can then conclude that $\frac{1}{(1-x)^5}\equiv\frac{1}{1-x^5}$.

Comment: You may be interested in [OEIS sequence A004006](https://oeis.org/A004006): 0, 1, 3, 7, 14, 25,... .

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy that very much helps to clarify. Thank you!

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy Your argument works even if $5$ is replaced by $6$ but the corresponding result $$\frac{1}{(1-x)^{6}}\equiv\frac{1}{1-x^6}\pmod{6}$$ is false. The fact that $5$ is prime is key here.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh No, it doesn't work because the starting premise is not satisfied. You just didn't understand neither the question nor what I said. The question is 'Why the congruences of the coefficients of $(1-x)^{-5}$ imply that this is congruent to $(1-x^5)^{-1}$?'. What I said is that the congruences simply describe the coefficients of $(1-x^5)^{-1}$. Now revisit your example. Do you know that the coefficients of $(1-x)^{-6}$ are divisible by $6$ for all exponents except the multiples of $6$ in which case they are congruent to $1$? No, you don't have that. So, nothing I said implies ...

Comment: ... the congruence that you wrote.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy: Ok I thought that the statement in your first comment is the reason for the congruence. Your comment is actually a description of the given congruence rather than a justification for it.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh It is a justification of the congruence between the power series, given the congruences of the coefficients. The congruences of the coefficients is given and also computed already in the question. They don't need help with that. They are asking why from these it follows the congruence of the power series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you know the following

> **Theorem**: If $p$ is a prime number then $p$ divides the binomial coefficients $\binom{p}{a}$ for $a=1,2,\dots, (p-1)$.

Therefore we have $$(1-x)^{5}\equiv 1-x^5\pmod{5}$$ and taking reciprocals $$\frac{1}{(1-x)^{5}}\equiv \frac{1}{1-x^5}\pmod {5}$$

The key here is the congruence of formal power series with integer coefficients. Let $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx^n, \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_nx^n$ be two formal power series with integer coefficients. Then we say that $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx^n\equiv \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_nx^n\pmod{m} $$ if $a_n\equiv b_n\pmod {m} $ for all $n$.

Such congruences follow usual rules like one can add / subtract same formal series to each side of a congruence or multiply both sides of a congruence by same formal series and the resulting congruence remains valid.

Similarly we can take reciprocals of both sides of a congruence if resulting formal series have integer coefficients (prove it!). Note that this requires the formal series involved have their constant terms equal to $1$ so that taking reciprocals leads to integer coefficients.

---

Ramanujan was a master of such manipulation with formal series and products and he used this approach extensively. My guess here is that you encountered this technique in proving partition congruence $$p(5n+4)\equiv 0\pmod{5}$$

Comment: @Sirch You can avoid having to invert the series and re-proving that their corresponding coefficients are congruent, if as you did in your question, you expand $(1-x)^{-p}$ in series directly. The coefficients are $(-1)^n\binom{-p}{n}$, which give you directly the congruence. No need to do the same work twice.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy: the proof for inverting the series is almost trivial by induction. Once the rules for congruence of power series are established this itself becomes an effective technique.

Comment: Thank you for your help, this makes things much more clear! You are correct that I am reading about congruences of the partition function.

Comment: @Sirch: you may also have a look at [this](https://paramanands.blogspot.com/p/archives.html?m=0). Search for "congruence" in the linked page.